# Problem with CSS property visibility from Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

In the code below, the CSS display element is not being read by the Javascript and I don't understand why. After putting in a `debugger` statement I saw display was empty even though I set it in the CSS. I've been staring at it for a while, so I'm probably missing something obvious.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    div#image{ display: none; }
    div#url { display: none; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleVisibility(id) {
    debugger;
        var imageStyle = document.getElementById('image').style;
        var urlStyle = document.getElementById('url').style;
        alert(document.getElementById("image").style.display); // debug for stack
        if ( id == "image" ) {
            if ( imageStyle.display == "none" ) {
                imageStyle.display = "block";
                urlStyle.display = "none";
            }
        }

        if ( id == "url" ) {
            if ( urlStyle.display == "none" ) {
                urlStyle.display = "block";
                imageStyle.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="create.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="formType" value="create">
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="image" onClick="toggleVisibility('image');"> Image <input type="radio" name="type" value="url" onClick="toggleVisibility('url');"> URL
        <div id="image">
            Image div
        </div>
        <div id="url">
            URL div
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe javascript only can read the style tags on the element, not the css tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZnJm/)

You can't read css styles of attributes like that but an alternative is to check for an empty value and treat it like `display:none`

```
    if ( id == "image" ) {
        if ( imageStyle.display == "none" || !imageStyle.display) {
            imageStyle.display = "block";
            urlStyle.display = "none";
        }
    }

    if ( id == "url" ) {
        if ( urlStyle.display == "none" || !urlStyle.display) {
            urlStyle.display = "block";
            imageStyle.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

Comment: This makes sense. =) Stack won't let me accept the answer for a bit, but I will. Thanks!

Comment: *"...check for an empty value and treat it like `display:none`"* An empty value on most elements should be treated as `display: block` or `display: inline`, not `display: none`.

Comment: @TJCrowder I actually disagree.  A visible element will be either inline or block typically.  but invisible elements by the display property will always be set to none.  Basically, treating the blank value as inline only covers roughly half the elements.

Comment: @anjunatl np :) glad to help.

Comment: The `.style.display` property on the actual element doesn't tell you whether a stylesheet is hiding it at all, you can't "check for an empty value" and make any kind of assumption about whether the element is visible. For example, both of the `div` elements in [this example page](http://jsbin.com/alibot) report `.style.display` is `""`, but one of them is visible and the other isn't. **All** the `.style.display` property tells you is whether there's an inline style on the element. That's it, it doesn't apply to the OP's sample at all, which uses a stylesheet.

Comment: @TJCrowder I know that, but we aren't really checking if the elements are visible here. What we are doing is checking to see if we have set it before.  If we haven't, assume it's invisible. After the first time it hits it, it (element.style) will always have a value of block or none.

Comment: @TGCrowder and no... element.style also tells you if js has changed the element's style.  it will have a value after it's set

Answer (score 1):

That's because you need to get the computed style of the element.

You can do that using this function:

```
function getStyle( elem, name ) {
    var value;

    if (elem.currentStyle) {
        value = elem.currentStyle[name];
    } else if (window.getComputedStyle) {
        value = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue(name);
    }
    return value;       
}
```

I've also simplified part of your JS, so you probably wouldn't need to check the style of the element anyway:

```
if ( id == "image" ) {
    imageStyle.display = "block";
    urlStyle.display = "none";
}

if ( id == "url" ) {
   urlStyle.display = "block";
   imageStyle.display = "none";
}
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sNHKx/1/)

Comment: I knew something felt off/unnecessary in that block. Today's got a Monday-vibe to it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `style` property on `HTMLElement` instances only reflects the information for the *inline* styles for that element (e.g., the `style` attribute on the tag). To get the computed style of an element, which includes any applied by CSS rules, you have to use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3awindow.getComputedStyle) (on browsers that support it) or [`currentStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (on browsers that support it).

---

**Slightly off-topic**: Reliably getting the computed style for an element is one of the (many) areas where a good JavaScript library can save you a lot of time and trouble, whether it's [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). It's not just the `getComputedStyle` / `currentStyle` dichotomy, but various browser quirks as well. Using a good library, you can leverage the huge amount of work and research others have done, so you can concentrate on your specific work. Usually. :-)

For instance, using jQuery you could find out whether the element with the `id` "image" was visible (which can be affected by `display: none`, `visibility: hidden`, etc.) like this:

```
if ($("#image").visible()) {
    // Yes it is
}
```

Or if you want to check a specific *computed* style:

```
if ($("#image").css("display") === "none") {
    // It has display: none, either directly or by rule
}
```

Other libraries will have similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't natively read styles from elements as set in a style sheet. I think JQuery and other libraries do. In order to get this to work you could et the style attribute on the actual tag itself:

```
<div id="image" style="display:none">
    Image div
</div>
<div id="url" style="display:none">
    URL div
</div>
```

Or, check for an empty value and use that as "none"

Comment: You're right, I was confusing it with JQuery's functionality. I'd just use JQuery here but that's a large library and I don't have a need for it on this tiny project. Thanks!